# Test Driven Development and KISS

Tags: php, unit-testing, tdd

For example I want to design a `Job` entity. Job has a status and I need to mark a `Job` as *done*.

I wrote a `markDone()` method and I want to test it. So to do an assertion I need one more method - `isDone()`. But at the moment I don't use `isDone()` method in the my code.

Is it ok to write such a useless methods to please a TDD?

Comment: You need to post some of your actual code in order for us to help you.

Comment: In TDD you are writing the code and the test so why do you write a useless test?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it ok to write such a useless methods to please a TDD?

Yes, but maybe not.

The yes part: you are allowed to shape your design in such a way that testing is easier, including creating methods specifically for observability.  Such things often come in handy later when you are trying to build views to understand processes running in production.

The maybe not part: What's Job::status for?  What observable behavior(s) in the system change when that status is set to done?  What bugs would be filed if Job::markDone were a no-op?  That's the kind of thing you really want to be testing.

For instance, it might be that you need to be able to describe the job as a JSON document, and changing the job status changes the value that appears in the JSON.  Great!  Test that.

```
job.markDone()
json = job.asJson()
assert "DONE".equals(json.getText("status))
```

In the domain-layer / business-logic, objects are interesting for how they use their hidden data structures to respond to queries.  Commands are interesting, not because they mutate the data structure, but because the mutated data structure produces different query results.

Answer (score 0):

If the method has no use outside of testing, I'd avoid writing it since there's probably another way that you can check whether or not the job is done. Is the job's status public, or do you have a method that returns the job's status? If so, I'd use that to test whether `markDone()` is working properly. If not, you can use [reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.getvalue.php) to check the value of a private or protected object property.

Comment: No, I'm avoiding of using *getters*. So probably there is only one solution - using reflection as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Can `isDone()' just reside in the test project and not the production code? That way, you wouldn't have useless production code just for the sake of testing.

Comment: Hm, in this case I will have to create test stubs that extends entity and provides `isDone`-like methods. I think it's overhead. Probably a reflection would be better.